# How can I resolve this error from symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

im using symfony and i keep getting this error

Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in /home/e1759631/public_html/TP1/var/cache/dev/ContainerKm4PF6B/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 890

any idea of what to do?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see your Repository ?

Please try to just change this `use` line from

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```

To

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```

Furher information here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository